# <type 'exceptions.GeneratorExit'>, GeneratorExit() in Python 2.7

Tags: python, exception

I'm using python 2.7 and getting this run-time error. 
, GeneratorExit() 
Is there a way to break while or for iteration without this GeneratorExit error?

Actually, my python script needs to parse varied number of lines (depending on timestamps, e.g  3 rows - 50 rows in one second bucket) through two generators. Once the buckets are full, two buckets are correlated and processed. For this, I break the iteration every time the two buckets are (dynamically) full.

How do I avoid this generator exception? Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: care to share some code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you will have to post some code that doesn't work, with data examples and the stacktrace/error message  - otherwise your question is too general... Or perhaps you could search for: python GeneratorExit exception

Comment: GeneratorExit is a normal exception that is raised when a generator reaches the end. It is handled normally by the for loop construct, and you normally do not see it. You will need to post your code to show why it is not handled in your code.